# Перевод сообщения о необходимости url картинок начинаться с https://

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, загрузка-изображения

Если в сообщении добавить картинку без загрузки на imgur, самостоятельно указав её url, начинающийся с `http://` вместо `https://`, то появится следующее сообщение:

> ```
> All image URLs must start with https://
> Upload to imgur or specify an HTTPS URL
> ```

> [image: скриншот непереведённого сообщения]

Мне кажется, его можно было бы перевести. Спасибо.

Comment: [Завёл баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303630/339911).